# Parent and child component compartive

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Create a child parent component in angular. Create JSON files with following Data parent.json

"Id":10001. "name":"John"

"Id":10002, "name":"Sam

"Id":10003, "name":"Tom"

"Id":10004, "name":"Tom"

child.json

"Id":10001. "age 20

lo 10002 "age":"50"

"id":10003. "age": "25"

}} Fetch the parent.json file over an http "get" method, and show the name in drop down of parent

component

On selection of name in drop down send id to child component. Child component will fetch the child. json file over http call, compare the id and show the age of the person in child component If the id is not present in the child.json will send message to parent component which will be

displayed in parent component

"No data present Create a service, 2 components(parent and child)

Note: Please conot share nodemodule.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem. Also, the JSON you have shared is not valid JSON. Please edit your question and try to use code blocks to format your question.

Comment: Don't worry, most likely no one will come after your "nodemodule" however sharing some code of what have you done so far might actually lead to getting some help.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code sample, instead of "**of**" rxjs operator you can call actual json files

Parent component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  parentData = [];  
  selected = "";
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getParentJson().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.parentData = data;
      }
    )
  }

  getParentJson() {
    return of([
      {
        id: 100,
        name: 'Abc',
      },
      {
        id: 101,
        name: 'Xyz',
      },
      {
        id: 102,
        name: 'Efg',
      },
    ]);
  }  
  
  childCallback(ev){
    console.log(ev); // YOU WILL RECEIVE MESSAGE FROM CHILD COMPONENT
  }

}
```

Parent component html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option *ngFor="let p of parentData" [value]="p.id">
    {{p.name}}
  </option>
</select>

<app-child-select [idVal]="selected" (callback)="childCallback($event)"></app-child-select>
```

Child Component

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-select',
  templateUrl: './child-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-select.component.css']
})
export class ChildSelectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() idVal:any = "";
  @Output() callback = new EventEmitter();

  data = [];
  selected = "";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(e){
    console.log(e.idVal);
    if(!e || !e.idVal || !e.idVal.currentValue){
      this.data = [];
      this.callback.emit({status: 'NO_ID_VALUE'});
      return;
    }
    const v = e.idVal.currentValue;
    this.loadData(v);    
  }

  loadData(id){
    this.getChildJson(id).subscribe(
      (r) => {
        this.data = r;
        if(this.data.length === 0){
          this.callback.emit({status: 'NO_DATA_FOUND'});
        }
      }
    )
  }

  getChildJson(id) {
    const arr = [
      {
        id: 100,
        age: 10,
      },
      {
        id: 100,
        age: 20,
      },
      {
        id: 101,
        age: 25,
      },
    ];
    return of(arr.filter(e => e.id == id));
  }


}
```

Child component html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option *ngFor="let p of data" [value]="p.id">
    {{ p.age }}
  </option>
</select>
```